# Conditional Expectation of an Exponential and Uniform Random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let's say X is an exponential random variable with $\theta$ and Y is an uniform random variable over $[0, T]$. How does one calculate $E[(X-Y)|(X>Y)]$?

Answer (score 1):

> Let $X$ denote an exponential random variable and $Y$ any nonnegative random variable independent of $X$. Then, $\mathbb E(X-Y\mid X\gt Y)=\mathbb E(X)$ is independent of the distribution of $Y$.

To show this, call $\theta$ the parameter of the exponential distribution of $X$ and note that $\mathbb E(X-Y\mid X\gt Y)=\frac{N}D$ with $N=\mathbb E(X-Y;X\gt Y)$ and $D=\mathbb P(X\gt Y)$. The independence of $X$ and $Y$ yields
$$
D=\int_0^{+\infty}\int_y^{+\infty}\mathrm d\mathbb P_X(x)\mathrm d\mathbb P_Y(y)=\int_0^{+\infty}\mathbb P(X\gt y)\mathrm d\mathbb P_Y(y)=\int_0^{+\infty}\mathrm e^{-\theta y}\mathrm d\mathbb P_Y(y),
$$
hence 
$$
D=\mathbb P(X\gt Y)=\mathbb E(\mathrm e^{-\theta Y}).
$$
Likewise,
$$
N=\int_0^{+\infty}\int_y^{+\infty}(x-y)\mathrm d\mathbb P_X(x)\mathrm d\mathbb P_Y(y)=\int_0^{+\infty}\mathbb E(X-y;X\gt y)\mathrm d\mathbb P_Y(y).
$$
For every fixed $y\geqslant0$,
$$
\mathbb E(X-y;X\gt y)=\int_y^{+\infty}(x-y)\mathrm d\mathbb P_X(x)=\int_y^{+\infty}\int_y^x\mathrm dz\,\mathrm d\mathbb P_X(x),
$$
hence
$$
\mathbb E(X-y;X\gt y)=\int_y^{+\infty}\int_z^{+\infty}\mathrm d\mathbb P_X(x)\,\mathrm dz=\int_y^{+\infty}\mathbb P(X\geqslant z)\,\mathrm dz,
$$
that is,
$$
\mathbb E(X-y;X\gt y)=\int_y^{+\infty}\mathrm e^{-\theta z}\,\mathrm dz=\theta^{-1}\mathrm e^{-\theta y}.
$$
Hence 
$$
N=\mathbb E(X-Y;X\gt Y)=\theta^{-1}\mathbb E(\mathrm e^{-\theta Y}).
$$
Finally,
$$
\mathbb E(X-Y\mid X\gt Y)=\frac{\theta^{-1}\mathbb E(\mathrm e^{-\theta Y})}{\mathbb E(\mathrm e^{-\theta Y})}=\theta^{-1}=\mathbb E(X).
$$

Comment: Thanks! One would expect that the conditional expectation would be  a function of $y$. But I guess the memory-less property of exponential distribution diminishes that?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: I presume $X$ and $Y$ are supposed to be independent.  Use the "lack of memory" property of the exponential distribution.

Comment: They are independent random variables. Memory-less property in my view doesn't help here since the conditioning is on another random variable. Or maybe I am missing something from your hint. Thanks anyway!

Comment: It's slightly subtle that the property works for a random variable $Y$ independent of $X$ as well as for a constant.  You can prove that by approximating $Y$ by discrete random variables.